# Can I transform a table with 1 value into a text format in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am using R.execute in Power BI to find the username of the current user to a computer. (our organisation works with sharepoint). this way I want to make a universally true filepath for any user. This M code is in a table that is standing on it's own. I want to form this table into a text format instead of a table so I can use it as a text variable for the filepath.

M code to find username:

```
let
        RScript = R.Execute("output <- read.table(text=system2(""whoami"", stdout=TRUE))"),
        output = RScript{[Name="output"]}[Value]
in
        output
```

Now, this creates a table with only 1 value. Any way I can transform this into a simple text value? Or perhaps select this single value to perform as a variable for my filepath??

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify row number and column name:

```
output = RScript{[Name="output"]}[Value]{0}[Column1]
```

Or, assuming, column name may be changed:

```
output = Record.FieldValues(RScript{[Name="output"]}[Value]{0}){0}
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked like a charm. I am new to working with M like this, is my assumption that {} signals the row# and in the second it is a referencing to both row and column?

Comment: In M the table is the list of records. So the first {0} is referring to the first item of this list (i.e. the first row of the table). Output of Record.FieldValues function is the list too (column values in the row). So the second {0} is referring to the first column's value.